# How can I create code with my criteria in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am new and learning R programming, I have some questions about my problems.

This is what the sample looks like:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
   vehicle_id                  location           time     for_hire_light
   <chr>                       <chr>              <chr>             <dbl>
 1 zzJcCfa6nuUF9A02Sud5fASxowM 100.50457,13.90834 05:19:37              0
 2 zzJcCfa6nuUF9A02Sud5fASxowM 100.51297,13.91534 05:21:37              0
 3 zzJcCfa6nuUF9A02Sud5fASxowM 100.51323,13.91548 05:22:37              0
 4 zzJcCfa6nuUF9A02Sud5fASxowM 100.50572,13.90243 05:24:37              0
 5 zzJcCfa6nuUF9A02Sud5fASxowM 100.50717,13.8986  05:25:37              0
 6 zzJcCfa6nuUF9A02Sud5fASxowM 100.50979,13.89154 05:26:37              0
 7 zzJcCfa6nuUF9A02Sud5fASxowM 100.51099,13.88835 05:28:37              0
 8 /+bx80f3gOoPMoFBsS+3xX6jpi8 100.6657,13.90103  22:41:30              1
 9 /+bx80f3gOoPMoFBsS+3xX6jpi8 100.66742,13.90093 22:42:30              1
10 /+bx80f3gOoPMoFBsS+3xX6jpi8 100.66916,13.90055 22:44:30              1
```

```
my.df <- structure(list(vehicle_id = c("zzJcCfa6nuUF9A02Sud5fASxowM",
"zzJcCfa6nuUF9A02Sud5fASxowM", "zzJcCfa6nuUF9A02Sud5fASxowM",
"zzJcCfa6nuUF9A02Sud5fASxowM", "zzJcCfa6nuUF9A02Sud5fASxowM",
"zzJcCfa6nuUF9A02Sud5fASxowM", "zzJcCfa6nuUF9A02Sud5fASxowM",
"/+bx80f3gOoPMoFBsS+3xX6jpi8", "/+bx80f3gOoPMoFBsS+3xX6jpi8",
"/+bx80f3gOoPMoFBsS+3xX6jpi8"), location = c("100.50457_13.90834",
"100.51297_13.91534", "100.51323_13.91548", "100.50572_13.90243",
"100.50717_13.8986", "100.50979_13.89154", "100.51099_13.88835",
"100.6657_13.90103", "100.66742_13.90093", "100.66916_13.90055"), 
time = c("05:19:37", "05:21:37", "05:22:37", "05:24:37", "05:25:37",
"05:26:37", "05:28:37", "22:41:30", "22:42:30", "22:44:30"),
for_hire_light = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)), 
row.names = c(NA,-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

In my raw data, it still has some vehicle id that junk. So, from the "for_hire_light" column, 0 = has passenger and 1 = no passenger. For example, some vehicle has only "0" value in for_hire_light's column and it doesn't make sense.
Based on the "vehicle_id " column, I want to query it like I ganna remove the row if they have only "0" or "1" value(They should have both).
So in each vehicle id, at least it has to start with 1 (after that 0) and end with 1.
As a result, my first output will contain like this;

| vehicle_id | location | time | for_hire_light |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ZKfjZ13x53D6mssc2Acqf6U5i3g | 13.74096,100.61629 | 09:49:12 | 1 |
| ZKfjZ13x53D6mssc2Acqf6U5i3g | 13.73853,100.61608 | 09:52:12 | 0 |
| ZKfjZ13x53D6mssc2Acqf6U5i3g | 13.73853,100.61608 | 09:53:12 | 0 |
| ZKfjZ13x53D6mssc2Acqf6U5i3g | 13.73853,100.61608 | 09:55:12 | 0 |
| ZKfjZ13x53D6mssc2Acqf6U5i3g | 13.74049,100.61578 | 09:56:12 | 1 |

So, at least in "for_hire_light" column should have values with 1 ... 0 ... 1

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Base R

The following code splits `my.df` by vehicle id, checks if there are at least two different `for_hire_light` values and returns that sub data set if yes, `NULL` if not.

```
out.df <- by(my.df, my.df$vehicle_id, function(x){
  if(length(unique(x[["for_hire_light"]])) > 1) x else NULL
})
do.call(rbind.data.frame, out.df)
```

### Package `dplyr`

Here the logic is the same, implemented as a `dplyr` pipe.

```
library(dplyr)

my.df %>%
  group_by(vehicle_id) %>%
  filter(length(unique(for_hire_light)) > 1)
```